# ExtJS Adding a new data type in FiltersFeature

Tags: extjs, filter

Good day!

Working on data filters (**FiltersFeature**). There was a need create drop-down list in the filters.

Created a new class **Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilterRC** by analogy with **Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter** (ux/grid/filter), only with ComboBox
That cap this class:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilterRC', {
extend: 'Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter',
alias: 'gridfilter.stringRC',
---------
```

Reset the filters to FiltersFeature:

```
var cnfFilter = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    autoReload: true,
    encode: true,
    local: false
};
```

connected to its grid (**Ext.grid.Panel**): `features: [cnfFilter]`

settings for the table columns I write the following:

```
this.columns = [
      {
       xtype:'rownumberer'
      },
    {text: 'Data1', sortable:true, width:150,  filter: {type: 'string'}, dataIndex:'RC'},
    {text: 'Data2', sortable:true, width:150, filter: {type: 'stringRC'}, dataIndex:'CodePost'}]
```

The problem is that the data type - **stringRC** missing.

Here is the procedure of **Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature**:

```
getFilterClass : function (type) {
    // map the supported Ext.data.Field type values into a supported filter
    switch(type) {
        case 'auto':
          type = 'string';
          break;
        case 'int':
        case 'float':
          type = 'numeric';
          break;
        case 'bool':
          type = 'boolean';
          break;
    }
    return Ext.ClassManager.getByAlias('gridfilter.' + type);
}
```

then check the type **stringRc** not. As it turned out all the data on the types of filtration loaded here this function:

```
createFiltersCollection: function () {
    return Ext.create('Ext.util.MixedCollection', false, function (o) {
        return o ? o.dataIndex : null;
    });
}
```

although I could be wrong. How can you add your data type to filter? Prompt please and sorry for my english.

**Update** (source code for stringRC)

source code analogy with Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter

```
var storeData = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
autoLoad: true,
idProperty: 'RC',
fields: ['RC', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6', 'field7', 'field8', 'field9', 'field0'],
proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: Ext.php.myPHPClass.myPHPFunction,
        reader: {
                  type: 'json',
                  root: 'data'
                }
       }
});

Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilterRC', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter',
    alias: 'gridfilter.stringRC', // new type alias

/**
 * @cfg {String} iconCls
 * The iconCls to be applied to the menu item.
 * Defaults to <tt>'ux-gridfilter-text-icon'</tt>.
 */
iconCls : 'ux-gridfilter-text-icon',

emptyText: 'Enter Filter Text...',
selectOnFocus: true,
width: 150,

/**
 * @private
 * Template method that is to initialize the filter and install required menu items.
 */
init : function (config) { // config for ComboBox
    Ext.applyIf(config, {
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        labelCls: 'ux-rangemenu-icon ' + this.iconCls,
        hideEmptyLabel: false,
        labelSeparator: '',

        typeAhead: true,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'field1',

        store: storeData,


        listeners: {
            scope: this,
            keyup: this.onInputKeyUp,
            el: {
                click: function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    this.inputItem = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', config); 
    this.menu.add(this.inputItem);
    this.menu.showSeparator = false;
    this.updateTask = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', this.fireUpdate, this);
},

/**
 * @private
 * Template method that is to get and return the value of the filter.
 * @return {String} The value of this filter
 */
getValue : function () {
    return this.inputItem.getValue();
},

/**
 * @private
 * Template method that is to set the value of the filter.
 * @param {Object} value The value to set the filter
 */
setValue : function (value) {
    this.inputItem.setValue(value);
    this.fireEvent('update', this);
},

/**
 * Template method that is to return <tt>true</tt> if the filter
 * has enough configuration information to be activated.
 * @return {Boolean}
 */
isActivatable : function () {
    return this.inputItem.getValue().length > 0;
},

/**
 * @private
 * Template method that is to get and return serialized filter data for
 * transmission to the server.
 * @return {Object/Array} An object or collection of objects containing
 * key value pairs representing the current configuration of the filter.
 */
getSerialArgs : function () {
    return {type: 'string', value: this.getValue()};
},

/**
 * Template method that is to validate the provided Ext.data.Record
 * against the filters configuration.
 * @param {Ext.data.Record} record The record to validate
 * @return {Boolean} true if the record is valid within the bounds
 * of the filter, false otherwise.
 */
validateRecord : function (record) {
    var val = record.get(this.dataIndex);

    if(typeof val != 'string') {
        return (this.getValue().length === 0);
    }

    return val.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.getValue().toLowerCase()) > -1;
},

/**
 * @private
 * Handler method called when there is a keyup event on this.inputItem
 */
onInputKeyUp : function (field, e) {
    var k = e.getKey();
    if (k == e.RETURN && field.isValid()) {
        e.stopEvent();
        this.menu.hide();
        return;
    }
    // restart the timer
    this.updateTask.delay(this.updateBuffer);
}
});
```

Comment: You're doing exactly right. I created a simple test case, and the `alias: 'gridfilter.stringRC'` has been enough for the new filter type to be recognized and created. My feeling is that the issue is in your filter's code. How or what is not working, precisely?

Comment: after I set up the whole thing, that is prescribed type **stringRC** settings columns:      

`this.columns = [
          {
           xtype:'rownumberer'
          },
        {text: 'Data', sortable:true, width:150,  filter: {
                type: 'stringRC'}]`   

    
I have lost the menu **Filters** in titles grid, as I clean the filter is available again. That's why I think the problem with the new type.

Comment: Can you show us the code for your `stringRC` filter type?

Comment: updated post (added source type stringRC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem . Initially did everything right , the problem lay in the name of an alias (alias: 'gridfilter.**stringRC**'):

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilterRC', {
extend: 'Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter',
alias: 'gridfilter.stringRC',
-----------------------------------------
});
```

I just replaced it . True yet figured out what was the conflict of the denomination .
As soon as you will have free time to understand. And so everything is OK

(obtained as a joke: suitable programmer son to the father and asks: " Dad , why every time the sun rises in the east ," the father , " and you're checking every day as " the son of "yes, check " father : " for God's sake do not touch my son , do not change anything , still working " )